# Access Control-Allow-Origin sin configurar el servidor

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo un sitio web en angular, pero me sale el error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL_DE_LA_IMAGEN' from origin 'http://0.0.0.0:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Por seguridad no he colocado la url completa de la imagen.

Como lo puedo resolver sin configurar el servidor, ya que esta en un hosting.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Siempre debes tener presente que cuando publiques codigo, texto, imagenes o cualquier tipo de contenido con informacion sencible ya sea contraseñas, numeros de identificacion y en tu caso informacion personal de una persona debes de reemplazar la informacion o en tu caso tachar los datos personales de la imagen o mejor aun no colocar la imagen.

Comment: Dale una leida a [Control de acceso HTTP (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), para que comprendas porque es el error

Comment: Ponte en contacto con el proveedor back4app.com y pregunta como puedes habilitar CORS, tbn puedes revisar la documentacion y los FAQ del proveedor.

Comment: Necesitas usar [cors](https://npmjs.com/package/cors) para que no te sala ese error